# Отмена всех действий макросом vba

Tags: excel, vba

Возможно ли макросом vba отменить действия совершенные руками?
Есть файл с данными и много формул, результаты формул правятся вручную. Затем нужно все вернуть как было до правок. ctrl+z решает проблему, но это очень много кликов совершить надо)

Comment: Excel, что ли? не-а... Application.Undo отменяет только одно последнее действие, и то с выпендронами. *Затем нужно все вернуть как было до правок.* Сохранить до правок, потом, не сохраняя последнего состояния, перечитать файл (ещё очень способствует ReadOnly флаг на файле).

Comment: Да, эксель. Так и делаю, но перезапуск файла занимает с пол минуты, не хочется ждать, вот и ищу способы) Спасибо

Comment: Похоже на поиск костыля при неправильных действиях. *результаты формул правятся вручную* - это как? Замена части формул значениями?

Comment: да, замена значениями, потому что в данный момент нет четкого алгоритма работы, приходится некоторые значения подправлять вручную, в зависимости от разных показателей. Можно конечно их все в формулы вписать, но и долго и запутано в итоге получится)

Comment: Вы не первый, который наступает на такие грабли (замена формул значениями). Меняют, потом плывет сортировка, путаются данные - концов не найти... Формулам - формулово, значениям - значениево :) Уйдите от этой порочной практики, иначе наживете еще большего головняка, чем при поиске откатов.

Comment: А по вопросу: при открытии книги сохраняется ее копия. После изменений и ручного сохранения копия заменяется или создается новая. При необходимости отката книга заменяется копией (если копий несколько -  список для выбора нужной). Все это можно прописать в макросе.

Comment: Согласен, но пока не выходит) Сейчас запаролил этот файл и захожу в режиме чтения, делаю правки и перезахожу

Comment: Сложновато это думаю, я хотел что-то типа "500 раз нажать ктрл z")

Comment: Еще раз (поверьте опыту): Вы ведете себя к еще большим проблемам. Можно в формулах ставить проверки, ограничения, но нельзя заменять формулы значениями там, где должны работать формулы. Меняйте подход к работе с данными.

Comment: Как вариант, если у вас известны адреса всех ячеек, где происходит правка формул, сохранять на скрытый лист их первоначальное состояние при открытии. При закрытии заменять обратно на первоначальный вариант